# Hotkey for the PrtScn button

Tags: linux, x11

I created a screenshot plugin and am trying to add a hotkey for the "Print Screen" button.

This is the code I use to create a hotkey, it works good, even though `XGrabKey` is returning `1` which I thought meant fail because it was "already grabbed".

But does anyone know the constant for PrtScn? I can't seem to find the `XK_???` value.

I tried `XK_Print` and `XK_Sys_Req` but neither of them are working.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `XK_Print`. I ran `xev` and Print Screen gave this output.

```
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xbd, subw 0x0, time 3103925, (400,-192), root:(400,631),
    state 0x10, keycode 107 (keysym 0xff61, Print), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

and `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` contains the following

```
#define XK_Print                         0xff61
```

But note that I only got a KeyRelease event, so at least on my desktop something (probably KDE hook for screenshots) else ate the press event before `xev` could see it.

Comment: Thanks very much! Ill test it out :)